# How can I start qBittorrent on system boot?

Tags: 16.04, startup, qbittorrent

So I've got a bit of an issue trying to get qBittorrent to start on boot. I'm running 16.04.

I've tried to start it by using a crontab @reboot, but this unfortunately didn't work. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 8):

Press the **Super key** on the Keyboard and search for `Startup Applications`

Click on `Startup Application Icon`

Click on the **add** button: [Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMW9b.png)

Fill the simple startup program form indicating the explicit path of the `qBittorrent` application (just the way you run it from terminal):

[image: Filled form example]